# React-Query refetchOnMount: false with invalidated query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I don't want my components to always refetch when they will mount and already have the query in the cache, so I did:

```
export const App = ({ props }) => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        refetchOnMount: false,
      },
    },
  })

  return (<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{...restOfMyApp}</QueryClientProvider>)
}
```

When I save some config I tried to invalidate my query with the first key and with that `queryClient.invalidateQueries()`. In the React-Query devtools, it did show that the query is invalidated, but it just keeps the same results and don't refetch the query.

How can I invalidate the query to be refetched, but don't have to launch the query everytime the component mounts?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What options are you using for the `invalidateQueries()` call? Have you tried `refetchInactive`? https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientinvalidatequeries

Comment: It does nothing more sadly

Answer (score 5):

if your query is active, it should refetch with `invalidateQueries`. If its not active, as others have mentioned, set `refetchInactive: true`.

> How can I invalidate the query to be refetched, but don't have to launch the query everytime the component mounts?

Often, caching is better described with a time-based approach, so the better solution to turning off the flags would be to set a `staleTime` to define how long your data is going to be valid, rather than to define certain points where you want / do not want a refetch.

if you set the staleTime for your query to, say, 20 minutes, none of the refetch events (onMount, onWindowFocus, onReconnect) will trigger a refetch in that time frame. invalidating it manually will still refetch it.

This would also be in-line with how HTTP caching works (think: `Cache-Control: max-age=60`)

to represent: fetch once, then never again (unless garbage collected), set `staleTime: Infinity`.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like there's a bug in your code; could you show how you're invalidating the cache, and your cache keys?

Using `refetchInactive` should definitely solve the issue for you (emphasis mine):

> When set to `true`, queries that match the refetch predicate and are not being rendered via useQuery and friends will be both marked as invalid **and also refetched in the background**

[Here's a quick demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-r1m7dm?file=index.tsx).

```
const client = useQueryClient();
client.invalidateQueries(YOUR_CACHE_KEY, { refetchInactive: true });
```